How to fix islands being offset from map, boundary comes from KML file uploaded to a site
I'm having a problem where islands (uploaded as part of a KML file) don't match up to the location of the island on the map when I upload them to a particular site (iNaturalist).  It affects whether or not certain observations are marked as being a part of the place, so is not only a display problem.
This is what the error looks like:

Notice that the shape of the island is also slightly different.
The problem is larger for this very southerly island, but also exist for some mid-latitude islands:

And in Jamaica it is very subtle; some mis-registration shows up where the overlay (my boundary) is shifted south, but it's so small I guess it could be the error in the file/data itself, although given the others I think it's not:

Jamaica South

Jamaica North
The data is coming from this shapefile (click About tab), the RESOLVE Ecoregions 2017 data, after being uploaded to Google Earth and the island exported as KML.
I also notice that in the Northern regions (Alaska ecoregions), the shapes from Eco-2017 are distorted compared to those of the equivalent regions which were already on the iNaturalist website. Same region, just as if projected differently.
This makes me think that it's a projection problem.
However, iNaturalsit only takes data as KML files, and I've recently discovered that they are all supposed to have the same encoding. So I figure it must be able to interpret my data, unless when I downloaded it as KML it had already not be exported properly.
I opened the .prj file of my data and this is the content:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

Which makes me think this is in WGS 84, although there may be different sub-kinds. I read that Google Earth Pro uses WGS 84, and that iNat uses a version of it to store places, though it may use something else to display them. Later, I uploaded the shapefile to QGIS, I exported as geopackage to be able to select just this island, re-imported the geopacage, set via 'Properties' the coordinate system to WGS 84, set the default CRS as same, exported the island as KML, and re-imported to iNaturalist, but I still get the same error.
Someone else had the same problem, here, but no solution, they think it's due to old data (which they were told by a professional GIS friend).
Do you think it's an 'old map data' problem? I mean, it only affecting islands lends some support to this, but it's not as if the islands change shape (of this magnitude) over time.
If it is a projection problem, how do I diagnose and how do I fix it?
I am a complete newbie to GIS (only for this project am I using it or have I ever used it).

There isn't really anything to be done when the vector data is poorly registered.to the raster. This might have been a datum transformation issue, or different sourcing, but at this remove its unlikely you have the information available to correct the situation, even if you were a transformation expert.

I would award this as the solution if it were an answer.

The data is wrong on the site. Nothing you can do, unfortunately...


Can you tell why it's messed up on the site? Do they have some different projection for their tile layer / visible layer than the underlying map? Would it look like this if they had used some out-of-date boundary when defining the ecoregion this island is part of? Is it common practice to use different sources for different regions of the globe?
